# Visualize the Completion of (the Ordered Field) of Rational Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordered-fields, ordered-rings

Every ordered abelian group $G$ can be completed to give a larger ordered abelian group $\bar{G}$. The original abelian group $G$ embeds into $\bar{G}$ as a dense subset, and every non-empty subset of $G$ that is bounded from above has a supremum in $\bar{G}$. The completion can be constructed using Dedekind cuts, or by Cauchy sequences or Cauchy nets.

I'm interested in the ring $\mathbb{R}(x)$ of rational functions in $x$. We can give this ring an order by saying that for any $f \in \mathbb{R}(x)$, $f > 0$ if and only if $f(x) > 0$ for large enough $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried, but failed to visualize the completion of this ring. I see how we can make the completion of $\mathbb{R}(x)$ into a ring as well. However, it can not be a field because all complete orderd fields are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

We can even embed all power series into this monstrosity: if $a_0, a_1, a_2 \dots \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_i \geq 0$, then let $f_n(x) = a_0 + \frac{a_1}{x} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{x^n}$. The supremum of all $f_i$ is an element of $\bar{\mathbb{R}(x)}$, which we can identify with $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_i} {x^i}$.

How can I visualize this space? Is it too large to *be* visualized?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *visualize*?

Comment: If you construct a completion using Cauchy nets, then you won't get the least upper bound property. Indeed take a lexicographic power of the ordered group of integers: the completion is the group itself (nothing is added).
You do get an Abelian ordered group. In the case of rational functions, you get something that is isomorphic to formal Laurent series.

Comment: @nombre I don't understand why you don't get the LUB property. To clarify, use the order topology to complete using Cauchy nets. Also, could you explain what you mean by "a lexicographic power of the ordered group of integers"?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I don't havea rigorous definition, but I would accept an alternative description of the space. Maybe it can be interpreted as a space of functions or sequences

Comment: @Theone A lexicographic power of $\mathbb{Z}$ would be the product group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ ordered lexicographically, e.g. $(m,n)<(m',n')$ if $m<m'$ or ($m=m'$ and $n<n'$). If $G$ is an ordered group in which $\mathbb{Z}^2$ embeds (here I assume that it is contained in $G$), then the set $\{0\} \times \mathbb{Z} \subseteq G$ (which has $(0,1)$ as an upper bound in $G$) cannot have a least upper bound $\alpha$ in $G$, for otherwise $\alpha-(0,1)$ would be a strictly smaller upper bound.